# Execute Commands Sequentially in Python?

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I would like to execute multiple commands in a row:

i.e. (just to illustrate my need):

`cmd` (the shell)

then

`cd dir`

and

`ls`

and read the result of the `ls`.

Any idea with `subprocess` module?

**Update:**

`cd dir` and `ls` are just an example. I need to run complex commands (following a particular order, without any pipelining). In fact, I would like one subprocess shell and the ability to launch many commands on it.

Comment: maybe you should write a shell script instead of a python script

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is an easy way to execute a sequence of commands.

Use the following in `subprocess.Popen`

```
"command1; command2; command3"
```

Or, if you're stuck with windows, you have several choices.

- Create a temporary ".BAT" file, and provide this to `subprocess.Popen`
- Create a sequence of commands with "\n" separators in a single long string.

Use """s, like this.

```
"""
command1
command2
command3
"""
```

Or, if you must do things piecemeal, you have to do something like this.

```
class Command( object ):
    def __init__( self, text ):
        self.text = text
    def execute( self ):
        self.proc= subprocess.Popen( ... self.text ... )
        self.proc.wait()

class CommandSequence( Command ):
    def __init__( self, *steps ):
        self.steps = steps
    def execute( self ):
        for s in self.steps:
            s.execute()
```

That will allow you to build a sequence of commands.

Comment: `subprocess.Popen("ls")` works.  However, `subprocess.Popen("ls; ls")` fails for me.  Error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 639, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1228, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: This failed because Popen expects a list as its first argument and just "ls" is equivalent to ["ls"]. It tries to find a executable with name "ls; ls" which is obviously not there.

Comment: Wouldn't the execute from CommandSequence class over ride the execute() from Command class? If so, then how does s.execute work?

Comment: lack of shell=True caused the same problem for me def do_shell(self, command):
        self.proc=subprocess.Popen(command,shell=True)
        self.proc.wait()

Comment: Code not even tested

Comment: Using `s = """my script with line break"""` and running it with `subprocess.run([s], shell=True)` worked well for me.

Comment: @Izaya many thanks for your comment! Using Python 3.8.10 I have been browsing various answers and only this one worked.

Answer (score 33):

To do that, you would have to:

- supply the `shell=True` argument in the `subprocess.Popen` call, and
- separate the commands with:

  - `;` if running under a *nix shell (bash, ash, sh, ksh, csh, tcsh, zsh etc)
  - `&` if running under the `cmd.exe` of Windows

Comment: Or for windows, can use && so that a command that errors out will prevent execution of the commands after it.

Comment: @twasbrillig Interesting; I didn't know that cmd.exe shared this command separator with Unix shells. I should update my knowledge. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you this is invaluable and was really hard to find.

Answer (score 6):

Finding 'bar' in every file whose name contains 'foo':

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
find_process = Popen(['find', '-iname', '*foo*'], stdout=PIPE)
grep_process = Popen(['xargs', 'grep', 'bar'], stdin=find_process.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
out, err = grep_process.communicate()
```

'out' and 'err' are string objects containing the standard output and, eventually, the error output.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the `subprocess.Popen()` function supports a `cwd` keyword argument, with which you can set the directory it runs the process in.

I guess the first step, the shell, is not needed, if all you want is to run `ls`, there's no need to run it through a shell.

Of course, you could also just pass the desired directory as an argument to `ls`.

Update: it might be worth noting that for typical shells, `cd` is implemented in the shell itself, it is not an external command on disk. This is because it needs to change the process' current directory, which must be done from within the process. Since commands run as child processed, spawned by the shell, they cannot do this.

Answer (score 0):

To be more simple, just type all the commands in a single list/tuple. Then just iterate over the list/tuple and pass it as an argument to the system() funtion of os module.

```
from os import system

cmds = ['cmd1', 'cmd2']

for cmd in cmds:
    system(cmd)
```

Answer (score -4):

below python script have 3 function what you went just excute:

```
import sys
import subprocess

def cd(self,line):
    proc1 = subprocess.Popen(['cd'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc1.communicate()

def ls(self,line):
    proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['ls','-l'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc2.communicate()

def dir(silf,line):
    proc3 = subprocess.Popen(['cd',args],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    proc3.communicate(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: it is incorrect. `cd` has no effect on the parent and it is likely that OP wants builtin into the shell command (`Popen()` doesn't run the shell unless you ask explicitly -- though it won't help in this case).