# Python: exception handling for subprocess

Tags: python, msbuild, try-catch, subprocess

I am creating a script to build visual studio. Here is a snippet.

```
try :
    subprocess.call('msbuild /m /verbosity:minimal %s\generate_rhapsody_all.vcxproj' % (bin), shell=True)
except OSError :
    print 'ERROR: run vsvars32.bat first'
```

How come the output of this when msbuild gives an error is

> 'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

and not

> ERROR: run vsvars32.bat first

But when i remove **shell=True**, the try catch work fine.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

"If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the shell. This can be useful if you are using Python primarily for the enhanced control flow it offers over most system shells and still want convenient access to other shell features such as shell pipes, filename wildcards, environment variable expansion, and expansion of ~ to a user’s home directory. "

if shell=True, it is as though you open a shell program and execute the command in the shell's context/environment, which will give you the exact msbuild is not recognized message. however, if you remove the shell=True argument, the subprocess library will handle the msbuild command instead.

Comment: Removing shell=True causes another problem. If I remove shell=True, the vsvars32.bat that was ran before this script would seems like it was not ran all.

Comment: the subprocess library has a number of features to help you with things you want to do, typically things like getting the output etc. what do you want to do that subprocess might not be able to provide?

Comment: i see.... not sure if this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359347/execute-commands-sequentially-in-python